# Get two random items from a list in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a list of items in Twig, that looks like this.

```
{% set listItems = [
    { "name":"Bob","title":"Director","text":"Bob like burgers." },
    { "name":"Sue","title":"Manager","text":"Sue loves cash registers." },
    { "name":"Tim","title":"Assistant","text":"Tim doesn't like anything." }
] %}
```

I would like to get two of the three available people randomly in Twig so that I can display two profiles in a block of my site. (Like a rotating double-feature!)

I cannot find a way using the Twig Docs to do this, but I may be thinking about it wrong.

Comment: You can install the [array](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Array.php) extension and then combine shuffle with @user1453870's answer : `{% for item in listItems|shuffle|slice(0,2) %}`

Comment: Array extension in official docs: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/array.html

Comment: This is the correct answer and it worked out! How best to mark this as the answer, @DarkBee?

Comment: @fiddlestacks I made it into an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install the [array extension](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Array.php) and then combine `shuffle` with @user1453870's answer :

```
{% for item in listItems|shuffle|slice(0,2) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set listItems = [] %}
{% set people = [{"name":"Bob"},{"name":"Sue"},{"name":"Tim"}] %}

{% for n in [0,9] %}
    {% for obj in random(people) %}
        {% if obj not in listItems and listItems|length < 3 %}
            {% set listItems = listItems|merge([obj]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/um1d9l)

It's not pretty. It's better if you prepare the random array in your controller.

[Twig Random](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/random.html) reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use Twig Extension, you can try this:

```
{% set listItems = [
    { "name":"Bob","title":"Director","text":"Bob like burgers." },
    { "name":"Sue","title":"Manager","text":"Sue loves cash registers." },
    { "name":"Tim","title":"Assistant","text":"Tim doesn't like anything." }
] %}

{# Init the new random list #}
{% set newListItems = [] %}

{# loop for two random items #}
{% for i in 0..1 %}

  {# set random item #}
  {% set item = random(listItems) %}

  {# add item in random list #}
  {% set newListItems = newListItems|merge([item]) %}

  {# unset item in original list #}
  {% set tempListItems = [] %}
  {% for elt in listItems if elt != item %}
    {% set tempListItems = tempListItems|merge([elt]) %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% set listItems = tempListItems %}
{% endfor %}

{{ dump(newListItems) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array called **rows**, there is no need for array extentions

```
{% set rand_row = random(0, rows|length -1 ) %}
{% for row in rows|slice(rand_row,1) %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the slice filter.

```
{% for item in listItems|slice(0,2) %}
 {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

See here for more infos : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will always return the first 2 elements, not random one's